# Is dependecy injection specific to obejct-oriented pattern?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, oop, service, dependency-injection

I come from server side language background (Symfony2). What I know is that dependency injection and service-oriented architectures are specific to object oriented programming. From their documentation:

> Structuring your application around a set of independent service
>   classes is a well-known and trusted object-oriented best-practice.
>   These skills are key to being a good developer in almost any language.

I am reading now a client-side framework documentation (AngularJS), precisely the dependency injection chapter. Is angularJs written with OOP? Someone please to help me understand.

Thanks for your usual help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of **dependency injection** is based on the following ideas:

- An entity (object, module, etc.) should not programmatically create the entities it depends upon.
- Those dependencies should instead be passed as parameters (**injected**) instead.
- This reduces unwanted coupling and allows other implementations to be substituted more easily (e.g., alternative data sources, stubs or mocks for testing)

As Doug Luce states in his answer, this concept can apply in other programming paradigms as well.  The term is most common in object oriented circles because:

- The origin of (programming) design patterns was object oriented programming.
- Dependency Injection can alleviate the tendency of large object oriented programs to become too tightly coupled, difficult to test and brittle to change.

In some situations, such as pure functional programming, there is less need for something like dependency injection (it tends to happen naturally).

In structural languages without object oriented features, the concept is still very useful (perhaps even more so).  Obvious and easily used mechanisms for dependency injection are not agreed upon in (non object oriented) structural languages.

Since JavaScript has both object oriented and functional features, I would expect AngularJS programmers to make full use of these features and use dependency injection when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you sir, I start understanding now. well explained

Answer (score 1):

When the concept is called "dependency injection," it's almost always couched in the verbiage of object-oriented patterns. But the idea of passing in a wad of executable code that the function can use only depends on the language system having a way to do that: function types, closures, monads, promises, or whatever might do the trick.